# Loading percentage of iframe

Tags: javascript, html

How to show **loading percentage** of iframe tag with javascript? I am using iframe tag and my program takes some time to load my program. So I am thinking off to show the user how much it is being loaded yet now. I searched about it and I got to know that it's not possible to do it with HTML5, so I guess it can be done with js

EDIT:

```
<iframe width="800" height="600" src="https://www.greenfoot.org/scenarios/26460?embed=true" style="-webkit-transform:scale(0.4);"></iframe>
```

Comment: Show some of your code for to understand your requirement

Comment: This can de done with JS or JQuery using .ready function, you can find alot just using google or stackoverflow's search engine!

Comment: @Jack Benson, here is what you wanted. I thought it would be reported as spam so i didn't provided it. <iframe width="800" height="600" src="https://www.greenfoot.org/scenarios/26460?embed=true" style="-webkit-transform:scale(0.4);"></iframe>

Comment: It is much easier to show a spinner icon during the loading time, instead of showing the process bar that tells the remaining time.